# How can i sort by more than one field in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

my question is, is there a way to sort by multiple fields in the same mongodb query? in this case, if i get the lastName in asc order, can i also get the email in asc order simultaneously. i will be attaching a link to the mongo playground where i've inserted some documents for easy demonstration. please visit https://mongoplayground.net/p/twSk6e53LtM

Comment: Your query is returning the data in ascending order for both fields. The only thing that needs to be considered here is the priority. If your first priority of sorting is lastName, then add it to the top.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/ - read docs

Answer (score 0):

Try with [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-sort%20syntax):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    sort:( {
      lastName: 1,
      email: 1
    })
  }
])
```